# ocultar columna

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenas noches tengo una tabla con un buscador  para cargar la informacion uso ajax ,quisiera saber como ocultar las columnas pero cuando escribo alguna palabra en los buscadores el cuerpo del body se vuelve a cargar por lo consiguiente las columnas se vuelven a mostrar.

Utilizo php base de datos mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor comparte el código que te da problemas y lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poder ver dónde está el fallo en caso de que lo haya y así poder ayudarte.